# Play loaded audio file with Tone.js web audio framework

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, p5.js, web-audio-api, tone.js

Hi I'm creating a simple upload page where user load their local files and play it. For hour, i'm not uploading to the server, just want to create a file input and then play the audio file with Tone.js if it's possibel.

I'm using to this test P5.js library and Tone.js audio framework, the code below:

```js
let inputFile, bttPlayFile;
let files;

window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let context = new Tone.Context();
let source;

function setup() {
  
  inputFile = createFileInput(uploadTrack);
  bttPlayFile = createButton('play');
  bttPlayFile.mousePressed(tooglePlay);
}

function playSound(arraybuffer) {
  context.decodeAudioData(arraybuffer, function(buf) {
    source = new Tone.BufferSource();
    source.connect(context).toDestinattion();
    source.Tone.Buffer = buf;
    source.start(0);
  });
}

function selectedFile(evt) {   
  files = evt.target.files;
  playFile(files[0]);
}

function playFile(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.result);
    playSound(e.target.result);
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

function uploadTrack() {
  inputFile.changed(selectedFile, false);
}

function tooglePlay() {
  Tone.Transport.start();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/14.8.32/Tone.js" integrity="sha512-USKCQh+O8BX/a2K06xPNTwduhmQvN/m9FhkR7PRysCRlPoqIItl7Qz3xVTZC/oIHe6g5XvnLHDUgGpRMZZTmFQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the moment, nothing happens and I want to understand why and how to proceed with this. Thanks!

Comment: Good [mcve], thanks. For future reference, you can simply [edit] your question instead of [deleting the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70909622/play-multiple-audio-files-loaded-by-user-with-tone-js) though.

Comment: Almost a month since this question, I founded a solution. I don't know why exactly, but the method decodeAudioData() seems not run with Tone.js class ToneAudioBuffer(). So, converting the file to a local URL (createObjectURL()), it could be passed off to Tone.Player to start the audio file. Here's the code: [Play loaded audio file Tone.ToneAudioBuffer](https://editor.p5js.org/leticiamayni/sketches/3icSjW6xQ). Inside code there are all references used to reach this workable example. Thanks everyone who helped! Bye

Comment: Thanks for the update, but why not post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) using this site rather than providing a link to an external site?

Comment: The link is now broken...

Comment: here's the code https://editor.p5js.org/llelell/sketches/3icSjW6xQ

Answer (score 0):

If you open the console of your browser you should see a warning.

> The AudioContext is "suspended". Invoke Tone.start() from a user
> action to start the audio.

I think it will work if you call `Tone.start()` in the click handler of your "play" button before you load and decode the selected audio file.

It's unrelated to your question but it should be safe to remove `window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext` from your code. Tone.js uses standardized-audio-context internally which should handle this for you.